# Displaying specific information from 1 SQL SELECT query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a database table that contains a bunch of different options and their values. The table has 3 columns which are ID, menu_option, and value. So one row may have the following information: 1, "menu_color", "#AB324B".

I want to display the value of each option on the page so the user can edit the option. Right now, i'm creating a query to get the info for each specific option. Like so

```
SELECT * FROM menu_theme WHERE ID='1'
SELECT * FROM menu_theme WHERE ID='2'
SELECT * FROM menu_theme WHERE ID='3'
...
```

Instead of making a new query to get the info per row, how can I make 1 query and distinguish what row I want to get the data from and display the data using php?

I'm aware of how to use php while loops with an SQL query, but I can't see how that would work with selecting specific rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
<?php
//select all the rows
$sqlSelect="SELECT ID,menu_option,value FROM menu_theme";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sqlSelect);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id=$row['ID'];
    $opt=$row['menu_option'];
    $val=$row['value'];

    $menuId="input-".$id;

    //create the label for the input
    echo "<label for='".$menuId."'>".$opt."</label>";

    //pre-populate the input with the name,value,id
    echo "<input type='text' name='".$menuId."' id='".$menuId."' value='".$val."'/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this should actually work fine. I'll use this method.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this

```
 SELECT * FROM menu_theme WHERE ID IN ('1','2','3')
```